# Why is "EXISTS" subquery not limiting to both WHERE conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

New to programming here.
I want to pull all the information in the 'employees' table along with their job title from another table but limited to 'Assistant Engineer' by using the 'EXISTS' subquery.

I tried this approach:

```
select e.*, t.title
from employees e
join titles t on t.emp_no = e.emp_no
where exists (
  select * from titles t
  where t.emp_no = e.emp_no
  and t.title = 'Assistant Manager'
)
```

When you remove the 'Assistant Engineer' condition and put it outside the subquery, it works but I want to check if it's possible to put it inside the subquery.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Edit your question and show the query -- *as text* -- that you are referring to.

Comment: What `EXISTS` is needed for here? Since this is already answered, the second query in the answer covers in full your question. Only one inner join is needed for the result you want.

Comment: the exists will filter on employees which have an 'Assistent Manager' title, but the join will make your resultset contain all titles of these (filtered) employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you remove the join which is useless and wrong in your case:

```
select e.*, 'Assistant Manager' title
from employees e
where exists (
  select 1 from titles t
  where t.emp_no = e.emp_no
  and t.title = 'Assistant Manager'
)
```

If you want to use a join then there is no need for `EXISTS`:

```
select e.*, t.title
from employees e inner join titles t
on t.emp_no = e.emp_no and t.title = 'Assistant Manager'
```

Comment: What is the purpose of "1" in the subquery? Is it because of the boolean value? Is TRUE or FALSE interchangeable with 1 or 0?

Comment: `1` after `SELECT...` is just a value used in EXISTS statements. It has no special purpose. It could be 0 or * or null. It just shows that *something* is returned (something exists).